# My youngest leopard gecko's eye started shrinking / deflating! Is this something I should be worried about?

Tags: health, reptiles, leopard-geckos, eye-disease

My littlest leopard gecko has always been a tad unhealthy. He was the tiniest lizard from his clutch, and he already has metabolic bone disease... His tail was also eaten off by a violent sibling (has since fully grown back and looks healthy)... Now his eye has started shrinking / deflating?

It was extremely difficult to take a picture of, but I'll try my best to get a few ones that explain what I'm seeing.

In the picture below, you can see the very thick eyelid compared to his right eye.

In the other pictures, he's mostly squinting.. Every time I tried to get a picture of the eyeball when it was open, he closed it...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for the delay of comments, but if you are in concern about the health of your animal, please visit a vet, instead of waiting for guesses of strangers from the internet.

Comment: @Allerleirauh I live in a rural region that doesn't exactly have a reptile vet anywhere nearby. My lizard is still eating, drinking, excreting and acting normal, his eye just doesn't look right. If his health started to decline, I would've gone out of my local area to find a vet. So I will wait for guesses of strangers from the internet for right now.